# Using Spring's MockMvc framework, how do I test the value of an attribute of an attribute of my model?

Tags: spring, junit, model, mockmvc

I’m using Spring 3.2.11.RELEASE and JUnit 4.11. I’m using Spring’s `org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc` framework to test a controller method.  In one test, I have a model that is populated with the following object:

```
public class MyObjectForm 
{

    private List<MyObject> myobjects;

    public List<MyObject> getMyObjects() {
        return myobjects;
    }

    public void setMyObjects(List<MyObject> myobjects) {
        this.myobjects = myobjects;
    }

}
```

The “MyObject” object in turn has the following field …

```
public class MyObject
{
    …
    private Boolean myProperty;
```

Using the MockMvc framework, how do I check that the first item in the “myobjects” list has an attribute “myProperty” equal to true?  So far I know it goes something like this …

```
    mockMvc.perform(get(“/my-path/get-page”)
            .param(“param1”, ids))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(model().attribute("MyObjectForm", hasProperty("myobjects[0].myProperty”, Matchers.equalTo(true))))
            .andExpect(view().name("assessment/upload"));
```

but I’m clueless as to how to test the value of an attribute of an attribute?

Comment: Can you add code where you put MyObjectForm instance into the model?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can nest `hasItem` and `hasProperty` matchers if your object has a getter `getMyProperty`.

```
.andExpect(model().attribute("MyObjectForm",
   hasProperty("myObjects",
       hasItem(hasProperty("myProperty”, Matchers.equalTo(true))))))
```

If you know how much objects are in the list than you can check the first item with

```
.andExpect(model().attribute("MyObjectForm",
   hasProperty("myObjects", contains(
         hasProperty("myProperty”, Matchers.equalTo(true)),
         any(MyObject.class),
         ...
         any(MyObject.class)))));
```

Comment: Are you sure that "myObjects[0]" is the right way to the first item of the model's array?  When I implement your solution I get the error 'java.lang.AssertionError: Model attribute 'MyObjectForm' Expected: hasProperty("myObjects[0]", a collection containing hasProperty("myProperty", <true>)) but: No property "myObjects[0]"'.  I have verified that my model does in fact have an array of at least one item.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else comes across this problem. I ran into a similar issue trying to test a value of an attribute (firstName), of a class (Customer) in a List< Customer >. Here is what worked for me:

```
.andExpect(model().attribute("customerList", Matchers.hasItemInArray(Matchers.<Customer> hasProperty("firstName", Matchers.equalToIgnoringCase("Jean-Luc")))))
```